# how to change styles on word in statement in react native?

Tags: react-native

how to change color and fontSize on word in statement in react native?

for example "hello world test"
hello and test is red but world is blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
hello
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>
    word
</Text>
test
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set many styles to different `<Text>` within another `<Text>` component, like:

```
<Text style={styles.blueText}>
  <Text style={styles.redText}>hello</Text>
  world
  <Text style={styles.redText}>test</Text>
</Text>
```